# How to get record from between only time in Symfony 2.2

Tags: php, symfony

I need to get record that created an given time:
My SQL Table is as below

```
Id | Createdat 
1    2015-12-28 19:32:40
2    2015-12-29 19:35:05
3    2015-12-29 16:33:15
4    2015-12-28 19:32:36
```

I need those result in between `19:30:00` to `19:35:00` so i get only three records like

```
    Id | Createdat 
    1    2015-12-28 19:32:40
    2    2015-12-29 19:35:05
    4    2015-12-28 19:32:36
```

I use Symfony 2.2

my function in repository is :

```
 $results = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('t')
            ->where('CAST( t.createdAt  ) BETWEEN :starttime AND :endtime')
            ->andWhere('t.status = :status')
            ->setParameter('starttime', $starttime->format('H:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('endtime', $edntime->format('H:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('status', 1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

but I got this error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 71: Error: Expected known function, got 'CAST'
```

Please help

Comment: check the field type [here](https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions/blob/master/src/Oro/ORM/Query/AST/Functions/Cast.php)

Comment: You can't use `CAST` in a query builder. Even if with the beberlei library. If you really need it, you can create a filter named CAST. But why do you need to cast something here ? Doctrine can handle your type easily

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config.yml

```
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    dql:
        datetime_functions:
            date:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            time:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            timestamp:      Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            convert_tz:     Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\DateTime\ConvertTz
        numeric_functions:
            timestampdiff:  Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Numeric\TimestampDiff
            dayofyear:      Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            dayofmonth:     Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            dayofweek:      Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            week:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            day:            Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            hour:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            minute:         Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            month:          Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            quarter:        Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            second:         Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            year:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            sign:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Numeric\Sign
            pow:            Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Numeric\Pow
        string_functions:
            group_concat:   Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\String\GroupConcat
            concat_ws:      Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\String\ConcatWs
            cast:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Cast
```

and this you select from date range

```
    $beginDate = new \DateTime($beginDate.'-'.$month.'-'.$year);
    $endDate = new \DateTime($endDate.'-'.$month.'-'.$year);
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->CreateQueryBuilder();
    $q  = $qb->select('count(i)')
    ->from('CrmSandboxBundle:Invoice', 'i')
    ->leftJoin('i.user','u')
    ->where(
       'i.date BETWEEN :begin AND :end'
       )
    ->andWhere(
            'u.id = :user'
        )
    ->setParameter('begin', $beginDate, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
    ->setParameter('end', $endDate, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
    ->setParameter('user', $user->getId())
    ->getQuery();
    return  $q->getSingleScalarResult();
```